# Setting up DBLink between two Sybase Databases

Tags: sybase-sql-anywhere, dblink

I am having dificulty finding anything on the net on this subject.

I am tasked with creating a DBLink between two Sybase Databases. At the moment it's not yet clear if they will be on the same server or on seperate machines in the same network. What I do know is that they are both gonna run on the same Version of Sybase SQL Anywhere 12.

All I can find is how to creat a DBLink **from** Oracle or MSSQL **to** Sybase.

I can't seem to find anything about Sybase to Sybase.

I am sorry if my terminology is a little wonky, I am new to Sybase/ASA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a terminology problem. SQLA has the concept of a Remote Server - which could be Oracle, MS SQL Server or another SQLA database. Once you have set up a Remote Server, then you can set up remote tables etc.

It doesn't make any difference to the way you use it whether the other SQLA database is on the same database engine, another engine on the same server or a completely different server. Don't forget that SQLA has no concept of a Master database, every database is autonomous.

There are a lot of details for v12.0.1 at this URL : http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1201/en/dbusage/ug-accessrd.html

In Sybase Central you will see an entry for Remote Servers in the object tree. The SQL commands are CREATE SERVER and CREATE EXISTING TABLE.

If you have problems it would be worth asking on the dedicated SQLA site: http://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/

Comment: That was it! Thank you! In SQL Anywhere it is called Remote Server and you use Proxy Tables as a "Link" to the Tables on the Server you connect to.